# Whats the quickest way to iterate through failed Bull.js jobs and delete them properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, shaka, bull.js

I have a problem with my video upload pipeline getting stalled and users looking at a "waiting" notification all the time. It is a video upload pipeline that converts the videos with ffmpeg and uploads to AWS. It seems that there are failed/stuck jobs in Bull.js and Im wondering the best way to delete them.

I have a setInterval function getting all jobs like so `let j = await videoQueue.getJobs();`. If iterate through each job in a loop, do I need to find the job in redis to remove it or do I just kill the job itself somehow? The job has a property: `_progress: 'undefined;conversion error'` which is specific to my application's error codes. Just... how do I get rid of the job peacefully to free it up for other jobs?

Comment: Do you need to remove the jobs one at a time, or could you use something like `clean()`? https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/develop/REFERENCE.md#queueclean